# H-bridge with 0-3.3 V output

Tags: analog, boost, h-bridge, motor-controller

I'm planning on using a H-bridge to generate biphasic pulses using two PWM output from MCU with 3.3 V logic. The output voltage of the H-bridge is fed into a differential input of a high voltage piezo drivers ([DRV8662](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8662.pdf)). By controlling the amplitude of the H-bridge output waveform, I thus control the amplitude of HV output of the piezo driver.

Here is my issue; since I'm using the H-bridge not in it's intended use (i.e.: motor control). I seem to struggle getting any H-bridge / MOSFET configuration to work with variable bridge voltage 0-3.3 V (coming from DAC); any voltage bellow 2 V'ish starts to output garbage.

Any pointer to help me resolve this issue?

I've been planning on using [DRV8837/8](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8837.pdf), an integrated H-bridge driver with 0-11 V input, but the IC seems to be out of stock for another year. So it's not really an option.

Comment: Why do you think you need a H-bridge? Does the eval board for DRV8662 uses a  H-bridge? No. So please explain.

Comment: You might be right. I was actually planning to test using a dual DAC to generate my two PWM pulse to IN+/IN- on the DRV8662 and thus obtain biphasic HV pulse on the OUT+/OUT-